# Using PHP-SDK to get the album details

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm tried get the details of an album using the PHP-SDK and facebook class, using the following code:

```
$data = $facebook->api('me/albums');
```

the code above return an empty array.

But if I try get the friends:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
```

works fine. Why? the permissions are same.

in 'pure' mode:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums/?access_token={$_SESSION['access_token']}";
$res = curl($url);
$json = json_decode($res);
```

too works fine.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, there's a discrepancy between 'me/albums' and '/me/friends' which is the leading slash. Typo, deliberate, or your problem?

Answer (score 0):

to get the alubms details of the currently logged-in user, you need to request for the "user_photos" permission too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have "user_photos" permission to access this resource.
Make sure the access_token you are using takes care of that.